# LaTex CV - Deedy Resume: How to change the font size of section titles?

Tags: xetex, cv

I'm working on modifying the Deedy CV template ([link here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/deedy-cv/bjryvfsjdyxz#.U2H9Kq1dV18)). I would like to change the size of the section titles. Does anyone know how I can do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See line 63 of `deedy-resume-openfont.cls`

```latex
\scshape\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\fontsize{16pt}{24pt}\selectfont \raggedright\uppercase}{}{0em}{}
```

Change it to something like

```latex
\scshape\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\fontsize{18pt}{27pt}\selectfont \raggedright\uppercase}{}{0em}{}
```

and you should be fine

Comment: It worked. Thanks @phil-elkabat!

Comment: How do I change size of text in bullet points?

Comment: Have a read of this document: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_sizes,_families,_and_styles
You just place the desired size (small, large, etc.) in front of the text you wish to change the size of. Hope this helps.